# Is there a nowhere differentiable norm on $\Bbb R^n$?

Tags: derivatives, examples-counterexamples, normed-spaces

> Is there a **nowhere** differentiable norm on $\Bbb R^n$?

The non differentiable norms that I know (e.g. the one norm $\|\cdot\|_1$  and the infinity norm $\|\cdot\|_{\infty}$) are non differentiable at a few points (basically the corners of the associated unit ball) but I can't find/build any example of norm which is differentiable nowhere...

Comment: All norms on a finite-dimensional space are equivalent (produce the same topology), so I'd imagine not.

Comment: @Math1000 I don't get your point... I mean the Euclidean $2$ norm is differentiable and induce the same topology as $\|\cdot\|_1$ which is not differentiable everywhere.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Rademacher's theorem: a locally Lipschitz function on a nonempty open subset of $\mathbb R^n$ is (Frechet) differentiable almost everywhere.

Comment: Combined with the [reversed triangle inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality#Reverse_triangle_inequality) this makes fully sense. Thank you !